# Nunit SkipNonTestAssemblies setting is throwing error on AssemblyInfo.cs file

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, nunit, visual-studio-2022

I been having some issues with NUnit test discovery taking a long time to load for me after any code changes for my test project that uses the TestCaseSource to get the parameters to use with my test cases. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and C# for my nUnit test project.

I was reading the documentation and though that the setting called SkipNonTestAssemblies might help me with the issue where test discovery taking too long.  I have the setting in my runsettings file, and it also stated on their documentation to add the following code which i don't know is literal sense or all my assemblies that the project uses.

Here is my runsettings file code .

```
  <NUnit>
<PreFilter>true</PreFilter>
<DefaultTimeout>5000</DefaultTimeout>
<SkipNonTestAssemblies>true</SkipNonTestAssemblies>
```

Here is the link on Nunit documentation that states that this following code  might be placed in AssemblyInfo.cs file that does not contain any test

[NUnitDocumentation NonTestAssembly](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/nontestassembly.html)

Here is my code when I created the AssemblyInfo.cs file and related error

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;




// In SDK-style projects such as this one, several assembly attributes that were historically
// defined in this file are now automatically added during build and populated with
// values defined in project properties. For details of which attributes are included
// and how to customise this process see: https://aka.ms/assembly-info-properties


// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible to COM
// components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from COM, set the ComVisible
// attribute to true on that type.
//[assembly: ]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: NonTestAssembly]


// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM.

[assembly: Guid("8560f4ea-71d1-441e-93e7-5b9a32898166")]
```

I get the error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'NonTestAssemblyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to add using NUnit and tried a few other things but could not get it to work
Currently I'm on
Nunit 3.13.3
Nunit Test Adapter 4.4.2
Visual studio 2022

I did a simple code to get all the assembly that my test use which is

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

This gave me all list of assembly that the test use along with the assembly that
has all my tests in them.  I tried to add some of the assembles to the AssemblyInfo file but kept getting error so this is my first time using this file, so I don't know what I'm doing that its not liking but I'm getting errors any of the assembly I tried to put there.  If there is another way to fix the issue with my test discovery issue taking a long time before I can debug my test that I'm not looking at I'm open to suggestion.